# Is there documentation for "FeynmanKacFormula" under "ItoProcess"?

Tags: differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

Under the command [`ItoProcess`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/ItoProcess.html) there are "Properties related to ItoProcess" and one is "FeynmanKacFormula". Where can I find documentation on this?

Comment: If you look under `Scope > Process Properties Extraction`, there is an explanation. Also [Wikipedia: Feynman–Kac formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula).

Comment: I know the Feynman Kac formula provides a probablistic solution to a second order pde.  No need to look at Wikipedia. I want to know what the command in Mathematica does.

Comment: _"The property "FeynmanKacFormula" gives a PDE whose solution $u(y,t)$ satisfies the conditional expectation $E[V(x(T))|x(t)=y]$ and terminal condition $u(y, T)=V(y)$."_ Is that not explaining what it does?

Comment: Thanks very much  Domen.   Found it!

Comment: This pde has to be solved for  t in [0,T] and x over the real line.   How does one use Mathematica to solve such a pde over the real line?